# PHP function move_upload not moving files to centos 8 server

Tags: php, mysql, centos

This is one question one tries hard not to ask because there is so much documentation on it.However i have sifted through all the links related to the move_upload function
Here goes I have an HTML from submits to a MYSQL database. Up to this stage everthing works the form through the PHP script below writes pretty well to the database the only problem is the move_upload function is not moving files to the server. My folder on the server is in /var/www/desenhos.

```
    
    $titulo=$_POST['txttitulo'];
    $participante=$_POST['txtparticipante'];
    $nome=$_POST['txtnome'];
    $sexo=$_POST['r2'];
    $dob=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['txtdate']));    
    $email=$_POST['txtemail'];
    $escola=$_POST['txtescola'];
    $responsavel=$_POST['txtresponsavel'];
    $profession=$_POST['txtprofession'];
    
    

     

    if(isset($_POST['categoria'])){
    
foreach ($_POST['categoria'] as $cat)
     {
       echo $cat;
     }
   
    $categoria=$cat;    

}
        
        $error=array();
    if(!isset($_POST['txtagree'])){
        
        $error[]='file not checked';
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
             jQuery(function validation(){
              swal({
               title: "Error!",
               text: "Lei e aceita os termos e condições",
               icon: "warning",
                button: "Ok",
               });

                });
           </script>';
        
    
            }               
        
        $tmp_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/';
    
    if(isset($_FILES['pimage'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['pimage']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['pimage']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['pimage']['type'];
      
        $f_extension = explode('.',$file_name);
 $f_extension= strtolower(end($f_extension));
    
  $f_newfile =  uniqid().'.'. $f_extension;   
  
      $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","pdf");
//  $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
        if(in_array($f_extension,$extensions)=== false){
        
            $errors='<script type="text/javascript">
             jQuery(function validation(){
              swal({
               title: "Error!",
               text: "O Sistema aceita apenas extensões JPEG:JPG ou PDF ",
               icon: "warning",
                button: "Ok",
               });

                });
           </script>';
            
        echo $errors;
            
            
         }
        
      if($file_size > 5097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 5 MB';
          
                   $errors= '<script type="text/javascript">
                          jQuery(function validation(){
                            swal({
                             title: "Error!",
                               text: "O tamanho do seu ficheiro é demasiado grande!Tamanho maximo 5mb!",
                              icon: "warning",
                                button: "Ok",
                             });
                             });
 
                             </script>';       
                           echo $errors;  
            }else{
           
          $photo=$f_newfile;
         $store = "/var/desenhos/".$f_newfile;
          
        if(empty($errors|| $error)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file( $file_tmp,$store);
            
            
          
        
          
     /*if(!isset($errors)){         */
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            
         $insert=$pdo->prepare("insert into  tbl_request(categoria,titulo,participante,nome,sexo,dob,email,escola,responsavel,profession,photo)
                           values(:categoria,:titulo,:participante,:nome,:sexo,:dob,:email,:escola,:responsavel,:profession,:photo)");
    
         $insert->bindParam(':titulo',$titulo); 
         $insert->bindParam(':participante',$participante);
         $insert->bindParam(':nome',$nome);
         $insert->bindParam(':sexo',$sexo);
         $insert->bindParam(':dob',$dob);
         $insert->bindParam(':email',$email);
         $insert->bindParam(':escola',$escola);
         $insert->bindParam(':responsavel',$responsavel);
         $insert->bindParam(':profession',$profession);
         $insert->bindParam(':photo',$photo);
         $insert->bindParam(':categoria',$categoria);
            
     $add=$insert->execute();
     $last_id=$pdo->lastInsertId(); 
            
         if($add){
            
                     echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function validation(){
                    swal({
                    title: "A sua Subscrição foi Adicionado com Sucesso! ",
                    text: " O seu número de Subsrição é cds'.$last_id.'",
                    icon: "success",
                    button: "Ok",
                       });
                        });
                       </script>';
         
             
                
             
             }  
               else{
                 echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function validation(){
                    swal({
                      title: "Erro!",
                      text: "Subscrição não Feito!",
                      icon: "error",
                      button: "Ok",
                    });
                        });
                    </script>';
            
      }
           
        }
      }
      
      }
         
        
    
}
```

No error is shown but when i got to the I see no files are added. I have also given the apache user 777 but even though.What could I be missing? I have seen others talking about editing the php.ini but on Centos 8 which I am running i cannot locate the php.ini.By the way all the permission a recursively set -R.If my folder has 777 permissions why is my script not able to move the files.
Thank you.

Comment: What you are trying to do is to upload a file to "/var/desenhos/", but your folder holding your site is "/var/www/desenhos".  I would strongly suggest you to upload your file to your current directory or a subdirectory. Please also check whether safe mode is enabled in your server

Comment: Hi Ken thanks for quick response, i have changed  created a folder named desenhos in working directory which i am refencing as "/desenhos" in my script. When i run find / -name php.ini -print i cannot find  the php.ini file . I am using centos 8.

Comment: please create a php script with <?php phpinfo(); ?>, then execute it and you will find the location of your php.ini

Comment: I have identified and added safe_mode = On to php.ini file but still cannot move the files to server.

Comment: After changing the php.ini, did you restart ?

Comment: I hadn´t but i just did but still to no avail.

Comment: @Ken Lee, that you so much enabling the safe_mode in php.ini and restarting resolved the issue.

Comment: Good to note that you fixed the problem. Happy Coding Bro !